# Attach jQuery code to run onLoad and on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation

I have the following code which gets the user's current zipcode and displays it for them in a div:

```
(function ($, geolocation) {
    if (geolocation) {
        geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            $.getJSON(
                "http://ws.geonames.org/findNearestAddressJSON?callback=?",
                {
                    lat : position.coords.latitude,
                    lng : position.coords.longitude
                },
                function (data) {
                    $(function () {
                        $('#zip').text(data.address.postalcode);
                    });
                }
            );
        });
    }
}(jQuery, navigator.geolocation));
```

The code runs `on document ready`, I believe. Is this the same as the code running `onLoad`? Anyways, is it possible to run this code when a button is clicked? I was thinking something like this would work, but using this doesn't produce the zipcode `on document ready`, or when clicking the button:

```
function update() {
    ...code from above
}
$('#button').click(function(){update();});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't run on `document.ready`, except for one part of the code (the one inside the `function (data) { }` call.

No, `document.ready` is different from `onLoad`. `document.ready` is when the DOM is accessible via Javascript (but not necessarily rendered / fetched); `onLoad` is when everything has been loaded (and presumably rendered --- think images, etc.).

To have the same function run on a button click, you're already down more or less the right track. You'd want to have a reference to the function:

```
var update = function ($, geolocation) {
    // blah
};
// this will call the same function like you're doing above
update(jQuery, navigator.geolocation);
```

Then have that run via a click handler:

```
// don't forget that this has to be in a document.ready handler
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#button').click(function () { update($, navigator.geolocation); });
});
```

Comment: Is this any way to test that the button is calling the original script again? I'm guessing I could log the result to the console?

Comment: Unless you nerfed the `update` function reference somehow (or it's not visible from where you're setting the `click` handler), you should be calling the original function. When in doubt, you can always try slapping on a `console.log()` call or something in it though.

Answer (score 2):

Put your code in its own function, and call that function on load. Then have your button `onclick(getZipCode())`, which will also call the same function. If you don't want it onload, remove it from the `$(function() {});` jQuery.

```
$(function() {
    //On Document Ready, call getZipCode
    getZipCode(navigator.geolocation);
});

function getZipCode(geolocation) {
    if (geolocation) {
        geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
           $.getJSON(
               "http://ws.geonames.org/findNearestAddressJSON?callback=?",
                {
                    lat : position.coords.latitude,
                    lng : position.coords.longitude
                },
                function (data) {
                    $(function () {
                        $('#zip').text(data.address.postalcode);
                    });
                }
            );
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**The code runs on document ready, I believe. Is this the same as the code running onLoad ?**

Well the `onload event` is fired when the whole page is fetched from the server and all image tags or other elements are loaded.That sure is to take a long time, Jquery uses its own defined event named `document.ready`, that get's fired when the page is ready to handle your scripts(that will happen before your document's loaded)

This is adapted from JQuery Enlightenment book :

> The window.onload native JavaScript event can be used to
>   programmatically handle when a web page has been completely loaded in
>   the browser. However, because the event indicating everything has
>   loaded does not fire until all assets (images, Flash, etc) are loaded,
>   waiting for this event can be rather time consuming. A better solution
>   would be to start scripting the DOM as soon as it is available to be
>   manipulated. jQuery provides a custom event that is executed after the
>   DOM is ready to be scripted but before the window.onload event fires.
>   This is a custom jQuery event called ready(). There is one argument
>   passed to this function which is a reference to the jQuery function.

And for the click function , where is your update function ? try defining it outside of your document.ready.